# User Profile Application Service Not Responding

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

I'm trying to delete user profile application service but error occur.And now it stuck with "processing". I already restart the VM several times but it still no response.

[image]

I tried delete it using powershell but its say object not found.

[image]

Is it related to my MSSQL db?should i delete mSSQL db manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error “Get-SPServiceApplication: Object not found”, it seems that the “User Profile Service” is already deleted.

Try to clear the SharePoint configuration cache and run a IISReset, then check again.

Check the steps in the article [User profile service application (Deletion or stuck on stopping)](https://sharepointops.wordpress.com/2017/01/16/user-profile-service-application-deletion-or-stuck-on-stopping/)

Comment: Im using sharepoint 2016 and the farm is in production. Is it ok for me to clear all the sharepoint configuration cache on live production farm?

Comment: It will not impact the performance of SharePoint. I recommend you doing this during off hours.

Comment: LIke the suggestion,i clear the configuration cache on the server.do i need to clear all server configuration cache in the farm?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to delete it by using PowerShell, Supporting Microsoft [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/delete-a-service-application)

First, open SharePoint Management Shell as administrator then type below commands:

```
$spapp = Get-SPServiceApplication -Name "User Profile Service"

Remove-SPServiceApplication $spapp -RemoveData
```

You might face some permission issue, so better go thru the supporting documentation by Microsoft first. (above link provided) then perform these above steps.

Comment: I tried the idea but its say "object not found".Maybe its already deleted.Do i need to clean the sharepoint configuration cache also?

Comment: After reboot, does the error still appears?

Comment: Its still appear.I also clear the sharepoint configuration cache on the server.Do i need to clear all configuration cache in my farm?

Comment: did you try to reconfigure the service thru configuration wizard? it might overwrite the existing user profile service, then you can remove it manually or by command. I am not sure about clearing farm configuration cache.

Answer (score 0):

1. After checking every server in my sharepoint farm, i found an
   instance in one of the server service status stuck at
   "stopping",when other server status is "stopped".Thats why it keep
   showing 'processing'.
2. Run the sharepoint products configuration wizard on that server to detach it from farm.
3. Delete old User Profile Service and create new User Profile Service.
4. Run the
           sharepoint products configuration wizard again to attach the server
           it from farm.